# How can I access user data on Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: javascript, botframework

If I'm correct `userData`, `privateConversationData` and so on are stored in some remote database. How can I access this database (for instance to clear it during testing process)?

Comment: What language are u using? Are you asking for accessing the database per se or just to access to the values stored?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I'm asking about accessing the database. Language is `javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For basic implementation, the 'all user state database' is not accessible, you can only do actions by user (like `/deleteprofile`).

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-general-problems) adds a chapter called `How do I version the bot data stored through the State API?`:

> The State Service allows you to persist progress through the dialogs
> in a conversation, so that a user can return to a conversation with a
> bot days later without losing their position. **But if you change your
> bot's code, the bot data property bags stored through the State API
> are not automatically cleared**. You will have to decide whether the bot
> data should be cleared based on whether your newer code is compatible
> with older versions of your data. You can accomplish this in a few
> ways:
>
> - During development of your bot, if you want to manually reset the conversation's dialog stack and state, you can use the /deleteprofile
>   command (with the leading space so it's not interpreted by the
>   channel) to clear out the state.
> - During production usage of your bot, you can version your bot data so that if you bump the version, the associated data is cleared. This
>   can be accomplished in Node using the exiting middleware or in C#
>   using an IPostToBot implementation.
>
> If the dialog stack cannot be deserialized correctly (due to
> serialization format changes or because the code has changed too
> much), the conversation state will be reset.

See also this [topic](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1943) on BotBuilder Github about storage.
And this [question](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1501) also for security regarding state

### Workaround

You can use your own Azure storage for your bot thanks to `BotBuilder-Azure` extension provided by Microsoft.

It is avaible on github [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure) and it:

> enable bot developers to integrate bots with specific Azure
> components.
>
> - Azure Table Storage: **Allows bot developers to store bot state in their own Azure Storage accounts**.
> - DocumentDB: **Allows bot developers to store bot state in DocumentDB**

So once you set this up, you may be able to get your data with javascript as it's your own Azure storage.

Comment: Thanks, @Nicolas, my suspicions are proven

Comment: I added another link at the end for the same kind of conclusion ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since it isn't specified I'm going to assume you are working in C#.

If you are able to use the IDialogContext object your can use that to access these stores.

```
//Access private conversation data
context.PrivateConversationData

//Access user data
context.UserData

//Access conversation data
context.ConversationData
```

After this you have a few methods to work with. The most important are `TryGetValue(..)`, `SetValue(..)` and `RemoveValue(..)`.

Comment: Thanks, @Xeno-D but that's not I've asked. I need to have access to whole database.